# Exception Occurred

Tags: c#

I'm constantly getting the same error.

[image]

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll 
Additional information: InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'.
```

The Code is:

```
private void radGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, Telerik.WinControls.UI.CellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CellElement.ColumnInfo.HeaderText == "logo")
        {
            if (e.CellElement.RowInfo.Cells[2].Value.ToString() == "Error")
            {
                e.CellElement.Image = (Image)imageList1.Images[0];
                e.CellElement.ToolTipText = "Error";
            }
            else if (e.CellElement.RowInfo.Cells[2].Value.ToString() == "Warning")
            {
                e.CellElement.Image = imageList1.Images[1];
                e.CellElement.ToolTipText = "Warning";
            }
            else if (e.CellElement.RowInfo.Cells[2].Value.ToString() == "Message")
            {
                e.CellElement.Image = imageList1.Images[2];
                e.CellElement.ToolTipText = "Message";
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: It sounds like `imageList1.Images` is probably empty. Have you at least checked that?

Comment: What is the question? From the description `imageList1.Images` is probably empty and hence the exception.

Comment: A breakpoint is your friend.

Comment: Possibly, `imageList1.Images` cannot be indexed using `int`.

Comment: It would be better if you could post the exception as a text.

Comment: @JonSkeet **imageList1.Images** is not empty. The images are displaying in column.

Comment: @AliHassanQureshi It seems to be empty at the time that exception is thrown. The images you see may be coming from another image list, or possibly you are clearing or replacing `imageList1.Images`. Please put a breakpoint on the first line of `radGridView1_CellFormatting` and run in the debugger. When the debugger stops there, examine `imageList1.Images.Count` in the watch window to see how many images are there. No need to guess.

Comment: @kiziu [That turns out not to be possible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz38zyat(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @EdPlunkett, if we assume, that `imageList1` is named based on its type, but it does not have to be ;)

Comment: @EdPlunkett I've already done this. The image count is 4. I don't know what's the reason behind this. Everything looks perfect.

Comment: @kiziu So there's some unknown entity, with a form designer auto-generated name, which has an `Images` property that the *compiler* thinks can be indexed with an integer, but which throws `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if you index it with an integer at runtime. BRB, gotta feed my unicorn.

Comment: So what is the type of `imageList`? Can you provide a [mcve] to demonstrate this? Basically, without more information we're just guessing.

Comment: @EdPlunkett this exception occurred only when I close the winform by clicking on (x) button. Otherwise it works perfectly.

Comment: @AliHassanQureshi I don't know what your program does differently then. You have to find out what happens when in your own code.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN says this

> The exception that is thrown when the value of an argument is outside the allowable range of values as defined by the invoked method.

about the [ArgumentOutOfRangeException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception(v=vs.110).aspx). It goes on to say that

> You are retrieving the member of a collection by its index number, and the index number is invalid.
>
> This is the most common cause of an ArgumentOutOfRangeException
>   exception. Typically, the index number is invalid for one of three
>   reasons:
>
> - > The collection has no members, and your code assumes that it does.
> - > You're attempting to retrieve an item whose index is negative. This
>   >     usually occurs because you've searched a collection for the index of a
>   >     particular element and have erroneously assumed that the search is
>   >     successful.
> - > You're attempting to retrieve an element whose index is equal to the
>   >     value of the collection's Count property.

My suspicion is that it's the first case here, i.e. `imageList1` is empty. So your `imageList1.Images[0]` throws the exception because there is nothing there.

To determine if this is the case try `imageList1.Images.Count`. Given you're looking at 3 elements in your code `Count` must be >= 3.

Comment: I've already done this. The images count is 4. If the list is empty then how would I be able to display the images on the winform.

Answer (score -2):

From the looks of it, you don't have anything in the array. Do a check to see if the indices are actually initialized, and then go on from there.

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's a comment which duplicates several existing comments.